# How can I adjust the reading speed for the mongodb?

Tags: reactor

```java
        Flux.range(1,100).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).subscribe(i-> System.out.println(i));
```

When the Flux emmiter to 10 , I want to delayElement to 1 minute to this subscribe
The background was when I read some data from mongoDB and write to Elasticsearch,
but I want to dynamic to control the reading speed and don't want to exhaust the mongodb resource.

```java
Flux<List<Document>> readFromMongoDB = getFromMongoDB();

product_2014.subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<List<Document>>() {
            int counter;

            @Override
            protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                subscription.request(1);
            }

            @SneakyThrows
            @Override
            protected void hookOnNext(List<Document> value) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (counter == 1) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
                else {
                    counter++;
                }
                upstream().request(0);
                upstream().cancel();
                log.info("aaaaaaaaaaa");
            }
        });
ParallelFlux<List<Document>> getFromMongoDB(String product,
            int size,
            MongoDatabase mongoDatabase,
            int parallel,
            Duration duration) {
        Publisher<Long> publisher = mongoDatabase.getCollection(product)
                                                 .countDocuments();
        Mono<Long> count = Mono.from(publisher);
        return count.flatMapMany(l -> {
            log.info("split counter");
            return Flux.range(0, (int) (l / size) + 1);
        })
                    .log().doOnSubscribe(subscription -> {
                        log.info("doOnSubscribe");
                    })
                    .parallel(parallel,1)
                    .runOn(scheduler)
                    .doOnNext(integer -> log.info("get page  = {}", integer))
                    .concatMap(page -> {
                        log.info("page in {}", page);
                        FindPublisher<Document> limit =
                                mongoDatabase.getCollection(product)
                                             .find(Document.class)
                                             .skip(page * size)
                                             .limit(size);
                        Mono<List<Document>> listDocument = Flux.from(limit)
                                                                .publishOn(scheduler)
                                                                .collectList()
                                                                .doOnNext(list -> {
                                                                    log.info("{} in list",
                                                                            page);
                                                                });
                        return listDocument;
                    });
    }
```

Why I can cacel the subscrition.And the Flux still emit the page element?
And how should I do?
I want to paralle to read from mongodb and dynamic control the reading speed.

Comment: Afraid I've no clue what you're asking - your question isn't clear at all. Could you rephrase?

Comment: I had update my purpose? And think unclear?please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I only see it like this:

```
       Flux.range(1, 100)
                .flatMap(el -> {
                    Mono<Integer> elMono = Mono.just(el);
                    if (el <= 10) {
                        return elMono.delayElement(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
                    }
                    else {
                        return elMono.delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(i-> System.out.println(i));
```

You examine each element and decide how to delay exactly this one.

Comment: If I want to dynamic adjust the speed? How can I do?

Comment: You can call any service method from that `flatMap` body.